# Realtime DATABASE

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
 function create(numero, tema) {
  var data = {
    idDiscurso: firebase.database().ref().child('/user_data/'+ user.uid +'/discursos/').push().key,
    numero: numero,
    tema: tema
  };

  return firebase.database().ref().child('/user_data/'+ user.uid +'/discursos/').push(data);
}
```

I have this code to push data to my realtime database, but always when I run the code it sends the wrong key.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTsXv.png)

I like to add equal keys in "idDiscurso" and child.key, Tnx for help me

Answer (score 1):

`push` always creates a **new** random key. Instead of `push`, you'll want to use `set`, but I understand that you want `idDiscurso` to be the same ID as the push ID, right? So instead of using `push`, add `idDiscurso` to the child path you create, then set the data with `set`.

```
 function create(numero, tema) {
  var data = {
    idDiscurso: firebase.database().ref().child('/user_data/'+ user.uid +'/discursos/').push().key,
    numero: numero,
    tema: tema
  };

  return firebase.database().ref().child('/user_data/'+ user.uid +'/discursos/'+ data.idDiscurso).set(data);
}
```